# Relationship between pKa and pKb

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $38$. Does it stand for the following equilibrium:

$$\ce{NH4+ <=> NH3 + H+} \tag{1}$$ With $K_\mathrm{a} = 10^{-38}$ for reaction $(1)$, indicating that the conjugate acid of $\ce{NH3}$ is quite weak?

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $4.74$. Does it stand for the following equilibrium:

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + OH-} \tag{2}$$ With $K_\mathrm{b} = 10^{-4.74}$ for reaction $(1)$, indicating that $\ce{NH3}$ is a weak base?

Also: $$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 42.74 \neq 14$$

Comment: Regarding the last equation, it is only applicable to the sum of the pKa of a species HX and the pKb of its conjugate base, X-. Since both the pK values above are referring to NH3 itself, the formula is not valid. However, if you were to add pKa(NH4+) and pKb(NH3), you would indeed get 14.

Answer (score 11):

> The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $38$.

This means, the reaction this value is describing is:

$$\ce{NH3 <=> NH2- + H+}$$

> The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $4.74$.

This means, the reaction this value is describing is:

$$\ce{NH3 + H+ <=> NH4+}$$

---

There is a lot of misuse going on with the term $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ since many people are too lazy to say

> The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NH3}$’s conjugate acid is $9.26$
>
> $$\ce{NH4+ <=> NH3 + H+}$$

rather than

> <strike>The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ is $9.26$.</strike>
>
> $$\ce{NH3 <=> NH2- + H+}$$

but that is really what they should be doing. Thankfully, when looking up values in a table the person compiling the table (hopefully) knew what they were doing and used the correct terminology.

Only for a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ and a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ that describe the same reaction (from opposite viewpoints) is it true that $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 14$.

Comment: Since the pKa of ammonia is 38, does that mean the pKb of the azanide ion is -24?

Comment: @LamGyro Yes. One bloody hell of a strong base.